# Colliding objects due to gravitational attraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

If two objects initially at rest, are released and move toward one another due to gravitational attraction, they collide and exchange during collision some amount of impulse, i.e. the object 1 transfers to the object 2 $\Delta p_2$, and the object 2 transfers to the object 1 $\Delta p_1$. If the masses are different, $m_1 > m_2$, the movement of which object is more affected due to the collision, that of the massive object or that of the lighter object? I mean, denoting by $p_1$ and $p_2$ the two linear momenta just before the collision, then we have $\Delta p_1/p_1 > \Delta p_2/p_2$, or we have the opposite?

Comment: You've already stated that impluse is change in momentum.  You should also know that the total momentum of this system (with only internal forces) is constant.  So you can draw a conclusion even without examining forces.

Comment: This seems off topic since I don't really see that you're asking anything more than whether your reasoning is correct. That's not asking about a physics concept. You did many things _right_ in posting this question - quoting the problem, explaining what you tried and showing your reasoning, and narrowing down the specific thing you're confused about - the problem is simply that the specific thing you're confused about, as far as I can tell, is just whether you got the right answer, and we don't handle those kinds of questions here. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Maybe you can edit your question to make it clearer what you're really uncertain about? In other words, you've come up with an answer; now what makes you think it might not be the right answer? Does something seem inconsistent or wrong about it? (While you're at it, you may also want to [fix the title](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles), but you can get help with that once you narrow down your specific problem.)

Comment: @DavidZ Well in truth since I in a sense hit a wall when trying to solve the question that way, I went back to what I had said earlier (Impulse = Ft). Since the only force being applied is the same for both objects and time is fixed, the impulse for both of them would have to be the same. Im not just seeing how from what I had said before (that m1 > m2 and v1 < v2) could help me in solving this without knowing tangible numbers.

Comment: From Newton's third law, the forces are the same, and the time that they act are the same. That is independent of the mass of the objects. You are making this much too hard for yourself. Take a step back.

Comment: @Smith : I would like to try reopening your question. For this purpose the question should be reformulated. I saved the former version of your question, and I replaced it with another formulation that I want to propose instead. Please have a look at my formulation. If it displeases you I can restore the former one. If you approve it, can you notify me, i.e. write a comment for me?

Comment: @DavidZ : would you undelete my answer now? Please read its now form, would you?

Comment: @Sofia no, it's too soon. By the way, your edit was pretty drastic, and probably not the kind of edit one should normally make... hopefully Smith gets back to us soon about whether it's acceptable.

Comment: @DavidZ what you mean by drastic? I.e. I cut too much? Well, all these things that I cut, were simply futile, Smith tried to show us that he yes invested some effort, but it led him nowhere. The path he tried for solving his problem wasn't the good one. Well, we will see if he returns to us. But, maybe he found the putting of his question on hold, as very deceiving. God knows !

Comment: @dmckee : no, DavidZ told me that he found my answer non-understandable. Well, I found a way to make it simple. But the question of the OP was a very confuse one. I understood what he wants, but after reading the question again and again, a couple of times. --- On the other side, I don't know what to cut from my answer for not providing a complete solution, and still keep it useful.

Comment: @DavidZ My original question I thought was quite simple, but I made it confusing by presenting my thought process (It wasn't very organized). Simplifying the question: Would the momentum of the two objects be the same? From the different responses I got overtime I came to a final answer. The way the question was rephrased is not the exact answer I posted, but I feel if one were to answer it, I could draw information from that to answer my question.